# Case Sensitive Where Clause in LINQtoSQL?

Tags: linq, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I want to check whether a Tag (Case-Sensitive) exists in SQL Server 2005 table using LINQtoSQL. Let's say if a tag 'BEYONCE' exists in tags, then I want that I can add 'beyonce' or 'BeYOnce' but not 'BEYONCE' again. Here is the LINQ query i have written:

```
From t In Context.Tags
Where String.Equals(t.Tag, myTag, StringComparison.Ordinal) = True
```

But it says Method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)' has no supported translation to SQL. What's the other way to find case sensitive tag?

Comment: Is the database case sensitive or case insensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the database has the default collation settings then 'blah' and 'BLAH' will be equal. I dont think you can do this natively with LinqToSQL but you could execute a query that forces collation at a column level... i.e.

String tag = "beYONCE";
    IEnumerable result = db.ExecuteQuery(typeof(Int32), 
        "Select * From Table1 Where Value COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = {0}", tag);

That query wouldn't return any results because the tag in the table has 'beyonce' in it and not 'beYONCE'. Changing the string tag to 'beyonce' would return a result.

If you want to alter your database's collation options try reading [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20080811231016/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-can-i-make-my-sql-queries-case-sensitive.html) article.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This Field's collation is: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1250_CI_AS and the field is defined nvarchar for multiple languages when i replace COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1250_CI_AS its not identifying case sensitive info

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it natively with linqtosql.

You could try a bit of [ExecuteExpression](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/27/linq-to-sql-part-8-executing-custom-sql-expressions.aspx) and some [case sensitive techniques](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/case_sensitive_search_in_sql_server.htm). It's not pretty, but it should get the job done.

---

**edit**
Not sure if you're using c# or vb, but here's some c# code. *I'm assuming your base table is called Tag*

```
IEnumerable<Tag> matches = Context.ExecuteQuery<Tag>(
    "Select * from Tag where Tag = {0} COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS", myTag
);
```

Heck, just for completeness, here's it in vb.net too :-)

```
dim matches as IEnumerable(Of Tag) = Context.ExecuteQuery(Of Tag)( _
    "Select * from Tag where Tag = {0} COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS", myTag _
)
```

This is much the same as [Chalkey's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054742/case-sensitive-where-clause-in-linqtosql/1054800#1054800) answer.

Comment: what will be the SQL Query for it? I'm using nvarchar(100) for this field and Collation is: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1250_CI_AS